# How to ignore source folder structure in gulp-sass?

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

I am trying to make "main.css" file to be directly in css folder.
However, I get this path "/css/Content/scss/main.css" and I want 
"/css/main.css"

```
gulp.task('sass', () => {
    const sourceFolder = path.join('.', 'Content', 'scss', 'main.scss');
    const distFolder = path.join('.', 'wwwroot', 'css');
    return gulp.src(sourceFolder)
        .pipe(sass({
            sourceMap: true,
            style: 'compressed'
        }))
        .pipe(cleanCSS({
            compatibility: 'ie8'
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distFolder))
        .on('end', () => console.log(`[${new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}] -> sass compilation complete...`));
});
```

Comment: BTW, it works in Linux but not in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want `main.css` to end up in `wwwroot/css` try changing to this line:

```
return gulp.src(sourceFolder, { base: path.join('Content', 'scss') })
```

Sorry but I cannot explain why your original code works on Linux.

From [glob base in gulpjs.docs](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/api/concepts#glob-base):

> Vinyl instances generated by src() are constructed with the glob base
>   set as their base property. When written to the file system with
>   dest(), the base will be removed from the output path to preserve
>   directory structures.

So with the `base` set as `path.join('Content', 'scss')`  that portion of the filepath will be removed, thus main.css will go directly into your distFolder with the parent folders removed.